# "TZInfo::DataSources::ZoneinfoDirectoryNotFound" while trying to start a new project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I got this error while trying to start a new Ruby on Rails project:

```
TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound: tzinfo-data is not present. Please add gem 'tzinfo-data' to your Gemfile and run bundle install
D:/friends/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'

Caused by:
TZInfo::DataSources::ZoneinfoDirectoryNotFound: None of the paths included in TZInfo::DataSources::ZoneinfoDataSource.search_path are valid zoneinfo directories.
D:/friends/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => app:template => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
       rails  turbo:install stimulus:install
You must either be running with node (package.json) or importmap-rails (config/importmap.rb) to use this gem.
You must either be running with node (package.json) or importmap-rails (config/importmap.rb) to use this gem.
```

The web told me to ensure `tzinfo-data` was in the `Gemfile` and then use `bundle install`, and no matter how many time I ensured it was there, this error has repeatedly occured! One thing I noticed is that whenever I use the `rails new` command, it automatically adds the platforms to the Gemfile. Why is this happening?

Comment: Have You tried to manually install tzinfo-data gem with gem install tzinfo-data?
Coul You also specify OS? Probably it's Windows but which windows :)

Comment: Yes, I've tried. I'm on Windows 10. Also, while I've given up and just installedit on WSL, I think this question could still be useful for others :)